# Heartbeat check for python-shell with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, python-3.x

I have a nodejs app that executes various python scripts using npm package 'python-shell'.

Though I am able to trigger a python script from Nodejs, how do I handle the case when a python shell is active throughout the day and I want monitor the shell’s heartbeat, so I can display its active/inactive status in a HTML table?

Comment: How do you work with that shell? Have you tried using `setInterval` to shedule a recurring nodejs task that pings python?

Comment: The python script periodically reads a log file and sends email alerts when needed. I'm using treading in Python script, threading.Timer(5.0, main).start(), to read the logs every 5 seconds. I could use setInterval of JS but I would have to rework on all my Python scripts. So this would be my plan B if I can't find a solution. I just want some way of knowing that the Python shell is still running on the PC and and display its status on a web page, that others can access, who don't have access to the PC where the pytho-shell is running.

Comment: there are python shell instances which will tell you about the termination of the running process on python shell, check out this link https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell